# Google Search on website

Tags: php, html, search-engine, google-custom-search

I want to put a google search bar on my site but I dont want to use Google CSE. Instead i want to use a input field and have the results on the normal page it would show if you were to google search

Answer (score 0):

The following form will do the trick:

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get">
Google this: <input type="text" name="q">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

By performing a search at google.com you can see for yourself that Google is using the GET method with `q` as the key for the search value.